# Randomize two List<string> in C# in same order

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have two string lists `en` and `en1`

```
List<string> en = new List<string>(new string[] { "horse", "cat", "dog", "milk", "honey"});
List<string> en1 = new List<string>(new string[] { "horse1", "cat2", "dog3", "milk4", "honey5" });
```

And I want radomize their content "Shuffle them" and put this radomized content to new two lists.
But I also want them randomize same way so lists after randomization will still be

`en[0] == en1[0]`

random content after randomization

```
{ "cat", "horse", "honey", "milk", "dog"}
{ "cat2", "horse1", "honey5", "milk4", "dog3"}
```

Comment: if en[0] is "horse" and en[1] is "horse1", I don't know how en[0] == en[1]

Comment: Why not just shuffle a list of indexes that point to the lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding to Jon Skeet's answer, a nice way to do the shuffling is `OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())` so the code would look like

```
var joined = en.Zip(en1, (x, y) => new { x, y });
var shuffled = joined.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList(); 
en = shuffled.Select(pair => pair.x).ToList();
en1 = shuffled.Select(pair => pair.y).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

Two obvious ways:

- Take a normal shuffle method, and change it to modify both lists at the same time
- Transform the two lists into a single joint list, shuffle that, then split them again

The second sounds cleaner to me. You'd use something like:

```
var joined = en.Zip(en1, (x, y) => new { x, y }).ToList();
var shuffled = joined.Shuffle(); // Assume this exists
en = shuffled.Select(pair => pair.x).ToList();
en1 = shuffled.Select(pair => pair.y).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

Third obvious way:

Shuffle a list of integers `0, 1, ... , Count-1` and use this list as indexes into the original lists.

---

**Edit**

This goes along this lines (for user38...):

```
List<int> shuffeledIndex = new List<int>();
for(int i = 0; i < en.Count; i++) shuffeledIndex.Add(i);
shuffeledIndex.Shuffle();  // Assume this exists

enshuffeled = en[shuffeledIndex[i]];  // instead en[i]
en1shuffeled = en1[shuffeledIndex[i]];
```

Comment: This was my thought also. Good one.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think @Jon Skeet's answer is better than mine (since I only know the basics about C# and probably for some other reasons... :P), however you could shuffle your lists manually with something like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<en.Count;i++) {
    int remainingCount = en.Count - 1;
    int exchangeIndex = i + (new Random()).nextInt(0, remainingCount);
    swap(en, i, exchangeIndex);
    swap(en1, i, exchangeIndex);
}
```

Of course you would need to write a swap function like `swap(List<string> list, int indexA, int indexB)`:

```
string tmp = list[indexA];
list[indexA] = list[indexB];
list[indexB] = tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first combine the two lists into one using the [Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx) function:

```
var zipped = en.Zip(en1, (first, second) => new { first, second }).ToList();
```

You'll then need a shuffling function to shuffle them. You could use the [Fisher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) in an extension method:

```
public static void FisherYatesShuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)  
{  
    var rnd = new Random();  
    var x = list.Count;  
    while (x > 1) {  
        x--;  
        var y = rnd.Next(x + 1);  
        T value = list[y];  
        list[y] = list[x];  
        list[x] = value;  
    }  
}
```

To use the extension method:

```
var shuffled = zipped.FisherYatesShuffle();
```

Now you can split them back out again into two separate lists:

```
en = shuffled.Select(combined => combined.x).ToList();
en1 = shuffled.Select(combined => combined.y).ToList();
```